# Change listview items text color while loading in Theme AppCompat

Tags: android, themes

I have an application with two themes, the first one has **Theme.AppCompat** for a parent and the second one **Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**. When using the second theme my item's text is more pale while still loading and using the first one it remains the same color (like shown in the pictures) . What can I do to make the text pale using the appcompat theme?
[image: faded text]
[image: not faded text]

Answer (score 1):

Since i supose that those are textView you could change the textColor of your textView in xml

```
<TextView android:
    android:text="Dropbox"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

where colorPrimary5 is a defined color in your colors.xml file

Comment: They are, but that will only change the color of the text in both states - loading and already loaded, leaving them still looking absolutely the same (not like in the picture) , it won't make it more pale while loading